# Add dynamic maps to a list in a for loop

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having few maps (which are dynamic). I want to add those to a list (List<Map<String,dynamic>>) -> like this. I tried to add by using .add but throwed an error

```
Error:
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' of 'function result'
```

Dart Code:

```
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> teamName = [{'teamName': 'Spartans'}, {'teamName': 300}];
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> captainName = [{'captainName': 'ABC'}, {'captainName': 'XYZ'}];
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> correctValue = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < teamName.length; i++) {
          for (var j = i; j < captainName.length; j++) {
            final Map<String, dynamic> currentValue = {
              'teamname': teamName[i]['teamName'],
              'captainname': captainName[j]['captainName']
            };
            correctValue.add(currentValue);
            break;
          }
        }
        print('end result is $correctValue');
```

I want my result to be like
`[{teamName: Spartans, captainName: ABC}, {teamName: 300, captainName: XYZ}]`

Comment: I tried the code above and it works fine. My output is `end result is [{teamname: Spartans, captainname: ABC}, {teamname: 300, captainname: XYZ}]`

Comment: I just dont know what to say! It was not working before and now it's working. I don't know why! Anyways thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> correctValue = [];
var teamName = [
    {"teamName": "Spartans"},
    {"teamName": "300"}
];
var captainName = [
    {"captainName": "ABC"},
    {"captainName": "XYZ"}
];
for (var i = 0; i < teamName.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i; j < captainName.length; j++) {
        var currentValue = {
            'teamname': teamName[i]['teamName'],
            'captainname': captainName[j]['captainName']
        };
        correctValue.add(currentValue);
        break;
    }
}
print('end result is $correctValue');
}
```

Your code works for me after a few modifications.

Comment: It is working fine, I literally just don't understand what is happening. It was not working for me but now it's working. Anyways, thanks for your effort :)